# Intuitive explanation for Why $0*a = 0$ in a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

It's known that if $ \left(F,+, *\right) $ is a field, then $ \forall a \in F, 0_F * a = 0_F$.

**Question**:
Is there any *intuitive* explanation for this? (Not a proof).

Because, after all, $ + $ and $ * $ are different operations.

Comment: Just the distributive law.  $b\times a=(b+0)\times a = b\times a +0\times a$.

Comment: And it is true for a ring too, even a rng.

Comment: @Henry I'm looking for an intuitive explanaton fr this, not a proof

Comment: The distributive proof is as intuitive as it gets: adding zero before multiplying has no effect, and expanding this means multiplying by zero must lead again to adding nothing

Comment: I don’t have intuition for this beyond the proof that lulu suggested. (I do have various ways of thinking about multiplication when our field is $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb R$, of course.) Since a field is an abstract setting and we have only the axioms to work with, it seems difficult to come up with a more intuitive argument that makes sense in the general setting. If $0 \times a$ were not $0$ then surely we would have modified the field axioms to make this result be true.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked post. OP asks intuitive explanation, not a proof.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bill Dubuque explained it in the linked comment: $0$ is that thing which if you add it to anything, the anything does not change. In fact, if there exists something such that adding $x$ to it does not change the something, then $x$ must be $0$. Well, by distributive law adding $0*a$ to any multiple of $a$ will not change it; so $0*a$ must be $0$.